# How do I make a syslinux file for an ubuntu partition that is not where syslinux is

Tags: syslinux

Sorry, i am a bit of an ubuntu and syslinux begginer, and i was just wondering where i can read some documentation using syslinux on ubuntu.

What kind of search terms and sites should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would adivse you to firs start at some official sites to understand how syslinux works:

http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/The_Syslinux_Project

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYSLINUX

As of 2010-10-19, Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat) uses Syslinux 4.01 with GFXBoot.c32 (now officially included) and includes several special patches to allow gfxboot to use some configuration directives that were originally intented to be used only with the simple menu modules (menu.c32/vesamenu.c32).